# Is there is way to make monthly/yearly payments or payments recurring in every 3 month period with stripe in flutter

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am using `flutter_stripe` package to for stripe payments in flutter. My application is subscription based. I have 3 packages namely, $ per month,$ per 3 months,$ for lifetime. I am not using a back-end for processing payments. Its all done on flutter using [stripe payment intent API](https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents). Right now I am only able to process payments once. But I need to process payments automatically according to the type of chosen subscription. Please, suggest me something. Do I need a back-end? Should I use another package?... Anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you will need a backend. You would want to build a Subscription integration, using Stripe's Subscription API. Here is a good place to start with: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/quickstart

Comment: Following the link in the accepted answer I seethe  to use `flutter_stripe` all data are passed to Stripe via their https API, which they strongly discourage (also because it make you NOT PCI Compliant. TO avoid missing PCI Compliance I would still have to set in my Node server all the endpoints to simply pass the data collected in my app ( card details etc etc) to Stripe vie the Stripe.js sdk I already use there( to create users, accounts payment intents etc etc ) What's the point of using this flutter_stripe package then? Using some methods equally named to Stripe API? Thanks.

Comment: The link in accepted answer is fundamentally wrong. Calling server-side API needs secret keys and it should never be done on client side, or you will expose your credential to the world.


You simply needs your backend to do server side works, and hide your secret key. To avoid PCI Compliance you would want to make sure no credit card information ever reach your server. The correct way to use flutter-stripe is their example app: https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/tree/main/example

Comment: Yes @orakaro . You are absolutely right. My mistake sorry :P. Guess I was just looking for an easy way out. Turns out that it is easy for me but will create a lot of problems for my product. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for correction and happy to help :)